# Error "The type initializer for 'PX.Data.PXCache' threw an exception." when logging into Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I was using this environment earlier today and everything was fine; I did a merge of code from another branch and now am getting the type initializer error when I try to log in.

I backed out the changes from the merge but I'm still getting the same error.  Any suggestions for fixing/debugging?

Comment: To get back to a working state, unpublish all customizations, open Acumatica ERP configuration wizard, select Perform Application Maintenance, select your instance in the grid, click on the arrow right of update and select Update only website. This will remove all user code and repair base product code to it's original state when it was installed.

Comment: Oh I forgot... since you can't login you can't unpublish.. Instead, just delete every '.cs' file in the 'App_RuntimeCode' folder of your Acumatica instance and if you have that remove Customization DLL from the bin folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebuilt the website from my visual studio customization project; I had to recreate the folder for this branch, since the folder had gotten deleted somehow.

Rebuilding the website did the trick!